# How to store data to a specific user flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

so I have a project, in that project I have an admin page to** add shipments** and **link it to a user** (then they can view their shipments) the quistion is: How can I **store** that shipment **to the user** that I want? **Using Firebase**. Simple answers please. **Thanks**.

Answer (score 0):

You want to be looking at persistent data such as sqlite in flutter
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite

Comment: I'm going to use Firebase

Comment: You need to make that clear in your question. I would suggest looking up tuorials how to use firebase

Comment: I edited my question. Could you suggest what should I write to find what I'm looking for? Because I couldn't find what I'm searching about.